# Unique ID for each class

Tags: c#

I'm want a unique ID (preferably static, without computation) for each class implementation, but not instance. The most obvious way to do this is just hardcode a value in the class, but keeping the values unique becomes a task for an human and isn't ideal.

```cs
class Base 
{ 
    abstract int GetID();
}
class Foo: Base 
{ 
    int GetID() => 10; 
}
class Bar: Base 
{ 
    int GetID() => 20;
}

Foo foo1 = new Foo();
Foo foo2 = new Foo();
Bar bar  = new Bar();

foo1.GetID() == foo2.GetID();
foo1.GetID() != bar.GetID()
```

The class name would be an obvious unique identifier, but I need an int (or fixed length bytes). I pack the entire object into bytes, and use the id to know what class it is when I unpack it at the other end.

Hashing the class name every time I call GetID() seems needlessly process heavy just to get an ID number.

I could also make an enum as a lookup, but again I need to populate the enum manually.

EDIT: People have been asking important questions, so I'll put the info here.

1. Needs to be unique per class, not per instance (this is why the identified duplicate question doesn't answer this one).
2. ID value needs to be persistent between runs.
3. Value needs to be fixed length bytes or int. Variable length strings such as class name are not acceptable.
4. Needs to reduce CPU load wherever possible (caching results or using assembly based metadata instead of doing a hash each time).
5. Ideally, the ID can be retrieved from a static function. This means I can make a static lookup function that matches ID to class.
6. Number of different classes that need ID isn't that big (<100) so collisions isn't a major concern.

EDIT2:

Some more colour since people are skeptical that this is really needed. I'm open to a different approach.

I'm writing some networking code for a game, and its broken down into message objects. Each different message type is a class that inherits from MessageBase, and adds it's own fields which will be sent.

The MessageBase class has a method for packing itself into bytes, and it sticks a message identifier (the class ID) on the front. When it comes to unpacking it at the other end, I use the identifier to know how to unpack the bytes. This results in some easy to pack/unpack messages and very little overhead (few bytes for ID, then just class property values).

Currently I hard code an ID number in the classes, but it doesn't seem like the best way of doing things.

EDIT3: Here is my code after implementing the accepted answer.

```
public class MessageBase
{
    public MessageID id { get { return GetID(); } }

    private MessageID cacheId;
    private MessageID GetID()
    {
        // Check if cacheID hasn't been intialised
        if (cacheId == null)
        {
            // Hash the class name
            MD5 md5 = MD5.Create();
            byte[] md5Bytes = md5.ComputeHash(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(GetType().AssemblyQualifiedName));

            // Convert the first few bytes into a uint32, and create the messageID from it and store in cache
            cacheId = new MessageID(BitConverter.ToUInt32(md5Bytes, 0));
        }

        // Return the cacheId
        return cacheId;
    }
}

public class Protocol
{
    private Dictionary<Type, MessageID> messageTypeToId = new Dictionary<Type, int>();
    private Dictionary<MessageID, Type> idToMessageType = new Dictionary<int, Type>();
    private Dictionary<MessageID, Action<MessageBase>> handlers = new Dictionary<int, Action<MessageBase>>();

    public Protocol()
    {
        // Create a list of all classes that are a subclass of MessageBase this namespace
        IEnumerable<Type> messageClasses = from t in Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().GetTypes()
                                           where t.Namespace == GetType().Namespace && t.IsSubclassOf(typeof(MessageBase))
                                           select t;

        // Iterate through the list of message classes, and store their type and id in the dicts
        foreach(Type messageClass in messageClasses)
        {
            MessageID = (MessageID)messageClass.GetField("id").GetValue(null);
            messageTypeToId[messageClass] = id;
            idToMessageType[id] = messageClass;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: The only question that comes in mind is: *why*?

Comment: Why don't use GUID?

Comment: Why don't u use GUID or HasCode of class?

Comment: GUID for the win

Comment: You could use the Metadata-Token of the class.

Comment: @AlexandreBeaudet I want the id to be consistent between instances of the same class, but different between each class type. In the example in the code, Foo and Bar both return with GetID(), but their values are different. Foo1 and Foo2 are instances of the same class, so return the same ID value.

Comment: I would use a hash of the full type name or something like that. Not 100% proof but unless you have a hell of a lot of these classes you should be fine.

Comment: @thehennyy Metadata-Token sounds like exactly what I need.

Comment: Doesn't the type name itself satisfy this condition?

Comment: @DaisyShipton - I need it to be a fixed length bytes or int.

Comment: The namespace and classname should be unique enough

Comment: SHA-256 hash of the class name with a cache? Very, very unlikely to get a collision, and you could write a unit test for it just in case... Do you need this to be stable between runs, btw? If not, that suggests other options.

Comment: Does the same value need to persist between runs, or is simply within one run enough?

Comment: `typeof(MyType).GetHashCode()`

Comment: To the downvoter: It would be helpful to know how the question can be improved.

Comment: (Didn't down-vote) It all honesty, this specific of a requirement, and even that fact that is somehow also needs to be relatively mindful of performance, just smells like poor design. I feel a better solution could be given if you posted/explained more about _why_ you need this, and allow some suggestions on design.

Comment: @ForeverZer0: I'm always open to better solution. I tried to limit the amount of information to make the question easier to answer. And questions that ramble off with multiple questions tend to get downvoted (its hard to win on SO).

Comment: It's like that normal people don't understand we game developers! this is exactly my question for the exact purpose!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is one suggestion. I have used a sha256 byte array which is guaranteed to be a fixed size and astronomically unlikely to have a collision. That may well be overkill, you can easily substitute it out for something smaller. You could also use the AssemblyQualifiedName rather than FullName if you need to worry about version differences or the same class name in multiple assemblies

Firstly, here are all my usings

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Concurrent;
using System.Text;
using System.Security.Cryptography;
```

Next, a static cached type hasher object to remember the mapping between your types and the resulting byte arrays. You don't need the Console.WriteLines below, they are just there to demonstrate that you are not computing it over and over again.

```
public static class TypeHasher
{
    private static ConcurrentDictionary<Type, byte[]> cache = new ConcurrentDictionary<Type, byte[]>();
    public static byte[] GetHash(Type type)
    {
        byte[] result;
        if (!cache.TryGetValue(type, out result))
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Computing Hash for {0}", type.FullName);
            SHA256Managed sha = new SHA256Managed();
            result = sha.ComputeHash(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(type.FullName));
            cache.TryAdd(type, result);
        }
        else
        {
            // Not actually required, but shows that hashing only done once per type
            Console.WriteLine("Using cached Hash for {0}", type.FullName);
        }

        return result;
    }
}
```

Next, an extension method on object so that you can ask for anything's id. Of course if you have a more suitable base class, it doesn't need to go on object per se.

```
public static class IdExtension
{
    public static byte[] GetId(this object obj)
    {
        return TypeHasher.GetHash(obj.GetType());
    }
}
```

Next, here are some random classes

```
public class A
{
}

public class ChildOfA : A
{
}

public class B
{
}
```

And finally, here is everything put together.

```
public class Program
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        A a1 = new A();
        A a2 = new A();
        B b1 = new B();
        ChildOfA coa = new ChildOfA();
        Console.WriteLine("a1 hash={0}", Convert.ToBase64String(a1.GetId()));
        Console.WriteLine("b1 hash={0}", Convert.ToBase64String(b1.GetId()));
        Console.WriteLine("a2 hash={0}", Convert.ToBase64String(a2.GetId()));
        Console.WriteLine("coa hash={0}", Convert.ToBase64String(coa.GetId()));
    }
}
```

Here is the console output

```
Computing Hash for A
a1 hash=VZrq0IJk1XldOQlxjN0Fq9SVcuhP5VWQ7vMaiKCP3/0=
Computing Hash for B
b1 hash=335w5QIVRPSDS77mSp43if68S+gUcN9inK1t2wMyClw=
Using cached Hash for A
a2 hash=VZrq0IJk1XldOQlxjN0Fq9SVcuhP5VWQ7vMaiKCP3/0=
Computing Hash for ChildOfA
coa hash=wSEbCG22Dyp/o/j1/9mIbUZTbZ82dcRkav4olILyZs4=
```

On the other side, you would use reflection to iterate all of the types in your library and store a reverse dictionary of hash to type.

Comment: Nice write up. Most people have been suggesting the hash, which is kind of where I was expecting to go but I appreciate the inclusion of a cache to avoid recomputing the hash each time the ID retrieved. The example usage and testing is appreciated too. In the end I wrote some code that iterates through all the MessageBase classes and makes a lookup dict, but the beauty is this also triggers the first hash of the IDs so all subsequent ID retrievals are cached.

Answer (score 2):

Given that you can get a `Type` by calling `GetType` on the instance, you can easily cache the results. That reduces the problem to working out how to generate an ID for each type. You'd then call something like:

```
int id = typeIdentifierCache.GetIdentifier(foo1.GetType());
```

... or make `GetIdentifier` accept `object` and *it* can call `GetType()`, leaving you with

```
int id = typeIdentifierCache.GetIdentifier(foo1);
```

At that point, the detail is all in the type identifier cache.

A simple option would be to take a hash (e.g. SHA-256, for stability and making it very unlikely that you'll encounter collisions) of the fully-qualified type name. To prove that you have no collisions, you could easily write a unit test that runs over all the type names in the assembly and hashes them, then checks there are no duplicates. (Even that might be overkill, given the nature of SHA-256.)

This is all assuming that the types are in a single assembly. If you need to cope with multiple assemblies, you may want to hash the assembly-qualified name instead.

Answer (score 0):

Have not seen you answer the question if the same value needs to persist between different runs, but if all you need is a unique ID for a class, then use the built-in and simple GetHashCode method:

```
class BaseClass
{
    public int ClassId() => typeof(this).GetHashCode();
}
```

If you are worried about performance of multiple calls to `GetHashCode()`, then first, don't, that is ridiculous micro-optimization, but if you insist, then store it.

`GetHashCode()` is fast, that is its entire purpose, as a fast way to compare values in a hash.

EDIT:
After doing some tests, the same hash code is returned between different runs using this method. I did not test after altering the classes, though, I am not aware of the exact method on how a Type is hashed.

Comment: Sorry, people are responding too fast =P It needs to be consistent between different runs. I'll put this into the question.